# Does this cryoEM micrograph show one or two macrophages?

Tags: cell-biology, microscopy, macrophage, cryoem

[image: A colorized cryoEM micrograph showing a cell which appears to have two lobules.]

Attribution: CC BY 2.0 DEED [NIAID](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Macrophage_(17195150690).jpg).

The [image description](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Macrophage_(17195150690).jpg) says "Colorized scanning electron micrograph of a macrophage," implying this is just one macrophage. Is this true? If so, what is the cleavage-looking feature in the middle of the macrophage?